# How can I create a semi circle inner border like this in css

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, border

[This is what I want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAfSv.jpg)
I dont understand what is it called and no idea as well how to create this border. Please someone help me

I tried using two divs with border radius on top of one . but did not get the result that I am expecting

Comment: Please add your Html code.